# Which plugin should I use when replacing FindBugs with SpotBugs on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, findbugs, spotbugs

I am using FindBugs now. I have heard that FindBugs is obsolete now. SpotBugs is the successor of FindBugs. I want to install SpotBugs plugins in my Jenkins.

I have searched on the Available Plugins area for SpotBugs but didn't found anything. Also did not found any clue or the relation of SpotBugs with Jenkins.

Where I can find the Jenkins plugin for SpotBugs or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The new home for SpotBugs is the [Warning Plugin NG](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Next+Generation+Plugin).
It is from the same developer as [Static Code Analysis Plug-ins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins) which you are probably already using.

The Warning Plugin NG is supporting both FindBugs and SpotBugs report files. Make sure are updating your build to actually be using SpotBugs and not FindBugs (see [migration guide](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html)).